# OTP verification using Java in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

The OTP is not sending to my phone number, and I cannot figure out why. I've been watching tutorial videos already on how to send the OTP from firebase, but still no answers found. By the way I am using phone authentication in Firebase.

This code is from my logIn.class

```
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
private String mVerificationId;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

     signup_btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    signup_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Sign_Up.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });


    back_btn = findViewById(R.id.backbutton);
    back_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    final EditText editphone = findViewById(R.id.editContact);
    final ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    final Button lgn_btn = findViewById(R.id.lgn_btn);
    lgn_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (editphone.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Enter Mobile Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } else {
                if (editphone.getText().toString().trim().length() < 10) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Enter Valid Mobile Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lgn_btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    if (otpSent){
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "TEST OTP Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (mVerificationId.isEmpty()){
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "TEST OTP Unverified", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }else{
                        final String getMobile = editphone.getText().toString();
                        PhoneAuthOptions options= PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                                .setPhoneNumber(countryCode +""+ editphone.getText().toString())       // Phone number to verify
                                .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout duration
                                .setActivity( Login.this)                               // Activity (for callback binding)
                                .setCallbacks(new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        lgn_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + phoneAuthCredential);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        lgn_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);

                                        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                            // Invalid request
                                        } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                                            // The SMS quota for the project has been exceeded
                                        } else if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthMissingActivityForRecaptchaException) {
                                            // reCAPTCHA verification attempted with null Activity
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                                        super.onCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        lgn_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        mVerificationId= verificationId;
                                        otpSent = true;
                                        // Correct order of statements
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OTP_verification.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("mobile", editphone.getText().toString());
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }).build();
                        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

                    }




                }

            }
        }
    });
}
```

This code if from my OTP_verification class

```
private EditText inpudecode1, inpudecode2,inpudecode3,inpudecode4,inpudecode5,inpudecode6;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_verification);


    TextView mobileText = findViewById(R.id.mobileText);
    mobileText.setText(String.format(
            "+63%s", getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile")
    ));

    inpudecode1 = findViewById(R.id.code1);
    inpudecode2 = findViewById(R.id.code2);
    inpudecode3 = findViewById(R.id.code3);
    inpudecode4 = findViewById(R.id.code4);
    inpudecode5 = findViewById(R.id.code5);
    inpudecode6 = findViewById(R.id.code6);

    setupOTPinputs();
}

private void setupOTPinputs(){
    inpudecode1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                inpudecode2.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    inpudecode2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                inpudecode3.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    inpudecode3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                inpudecode4.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    inpudecode4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                inpudecode5.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    inpudecode5.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                inpudecode6.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    inpudecode6.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!s.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                // When the last digit is entered, initiate the verification process
                String otp = inpudecode1.getText().toString() +
                        inpudecode2.getText().toString() +
                        inpudecode3.getText().toString() +
                        inpudecode4.getText().toString() +
                        inpudecode5.getText().toString() +
                        inpudecode6.getText().toString();

                // Call a method to handle the verification process
                verifyOTP(otp);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
private void verifyOTP(String otp) {
    // Implement the logic to verify the OTP using Firebase Authentication
    // Use mVerificationId and otp to create PhoneAuthCredential
    String mVerificationId = getIntent().getStringExtra("verificationId");
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, otp);

    // Call the signInWithCredential method to complete the authentication
    signInWithCredential(credential);
}

private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Verification successful, handle the signed-in user
                        Toast.makeText(OTP_verification.this, "Verification successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // You can navigate to the next activity or perform other actions
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                    } else {
                        // If verification fails, display an error message to the user
                        Toast.makeText(OTP_verification.this, "Verification failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // You can also implement retry mechanisms or other error handling here
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I wish I could be able to use my authentication with your help